# How to compares Istio to Docker Swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, istio

Reading the documentation about Istio I come with this questions.

Which are the points where Istio And Docker Swarm works the same?

Also, which one is better in different scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an apples to oranges comparison in many respects. Istio (currently) runs *on top of* Kubernetes, a container orchestrator like Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 6):

It's true that descriptions of Istio and Docker Swarm both refer the term "service mesh".

However, service mesh in Docker Swarm is more comparable to Services model seen  in Kubernetes, and the two orchestrators are generally comparable with respect to most features each of them has. In both of the orchestrators' service routing only touches network layers, and doesn't have a visibility into e.g. HTTP protocol.

> Please note that Kubernetes Ingress API should be considered separately, it actually sits above the service model, and is in fact implemented by an external controller, e.g. Traefik or HAProxy, and actually Istio brings another implementation of ingress controller.

While Istio is (approx) one level above an orchestrator, right now it runs only on Kubernetes, but it will very likely support Docker Swarm along with other popular orchestrators in the future.

More specifically, Istio's service mesh is much more advanced than what Docker Swarm offers (and, by analogy, what Kubernetes Services offer), e.g. it enables fault injection, and transparent TLS, among many other features.

Answer (score 3):

Docker Engine swarm mode makes it easy to publish ports for services to make them available to resources outside the swarm. All nodes participate in an ingress routing mesh. The routing mesh enables each node in the swarm to accept connections on published ports for any service running in the swarm, even if there’s no task running on the node. The routing mesh routes all incoming requests to published ports on available nodes to an active container.

Istio is an open platform to connect, manage, and secure services. Essentially, its an open service mesh, where we would like developers and operators to not have headaches about how to connect services, how to think about making them resilient, how to secure them, and how to manage the runtime. We would like Istio to be able to do that for developers and operators across all environments and clouds. And, when I say services its really all kinds of services not necessarily just micro. It could be anything like you are building MySQL API service, a really small micro-service within your application for payment or shopping, in any given language. So, istio takes an approach of working with a polyglot environment. You know, no matter which language you write your services in and where you have deployed, Istio would like to give you a uniform substrate between your application and network, which can take care of connectivity between services, resiliency between services. So resiliency includes things like retries, failover, all of the good stuff , and distributed systems securing services. We think internal services should be as secure as external once, so security by default. And, have complete observability and visibility of metrics all the way from L3 to L7 across all your services.

Essentially think about layer (some people called it L5) which is basically a layer between your application and network. And, when you think about it, you are basically creating, we are injecting the a proxy next to every service. And, those are in the data path of all service-to-service communication. They are all interconnected and also connected to a common control plane. And, that interconnected set of proxies which are living next to every service is what typically is being called as Service Mesh The reason it is so interesting is that once you think of mesh as a layer which exist as a network does, you can, at the application layer offload things like connectivity, resiliency, visibility to that layer. So, historically you could do this in either application libraries as if you are building in java, python or go there's bunch of libraries in each of these languages that you could import and write a logic into it. Or you could do L3 layer security and policy like IP white-listing, firewall rule setup, VPN networking, VPN peering, and so on. So, we think service mesh is a space between the two that can offload few things from L7 and give policy-driven contracts to operate your network. So, Istio service mesh is much better than the Docker Swarm service mesh.